# How to determine kernel stack size

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I need to determine the stack size of the running Linux kernel inside a kernel module. I do know that the macro THREAD_SIZE gives the stack size for a given architecture but I cannot use that. Since the compile and the run machines are different. Is there any way I could do this via a proc interface, kernel api or exported symbol?
Thanks

Comment: I think that it's safe to rely on THREAD_SIZE. For example if you compile your module for x86, you can be sure that THREAD_SIZE will always be PAGE_SIZE << THREAD_ORDER == 4K.

Comment: @strkol That's the whole problem. The kernel on which the module needs to work is a custom one. So this approach wont work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
system("getconf _POSIX_THREAD_ATTR_STACKSIZE");
```

`getconf -a` in console may output the list of system variables

Comment: Thanks @Nahuel, But I need the stack size of kernel thread and not the user threads

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it in thread_info.h of your architecture.
Normally the kernel stack is 2 pages (8KB) but it depends on your configuration.